# I downloaded windows 10 from a Windows 8.1 installation using the official GetWindows10-Web_Default_attr.exe. How do I save the downloaded files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

All tutorials I see on the internet say about a Windows_˜BT folder or something like that, and saving a .esd file extension somewhere else, but in my Windows 8.1 with Bing, after the download is finished, I just have a c:\ESD directory, with 2,39 gb, that looks exactly like a recovery disk structure but with a setup.exe that when executed gives a windows 10 installation prompt. I haven't seen any post whatsoever on google about this specific scenario.

I don't want to install Windows 10 yet, but since this free upgrade is for a limited time, I would like to know if, by saving this directory, I will be able to install windows 10 in the future.

Has anyone experiencied something like the c:\ESD folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the [official ISOs from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench) and store them on an external HDD so that you can use them later for a reinstall.

Comment: My system is Windows 8.1 with Bing. Don't know if this ISO is going to be compatible and will still need to burn the iso somehow to an usb flash drive.

Comment: The bing gets updates to Win10 Home. So download the Home ISO

Comment: You're right that it becomes Home, from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications, From Edition Windows 8.1 To Windows 10 Home, 4 Also applies to Windows 8.1 country specific editions, Windows 8.1 Single Language, Windows 8.1 with Bing. But since this download is a limited offer from Microsoft for a year, I don't know if I need the specific .exe that was downloaded.

Comment: More sources for the Windows 10 Home: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-to-windows-10-faq. And in the FAQ: Can I reinstall Windows 10 on my PC after upgrading?
Yes. Once you’ve upgraded to Windows 10 using the free upgrade offer, you can reinstall or perform a clean installation on the same device. You won’t need a product key to re-activate Windows 10 on the same hardware. For more info on how to create your own Windows 10 installation media, go to the Microsoft software download website.